# Why does loop.sock_accept(sock) block other co-oroutines in same loop?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

In the example below:

```
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(client())  # Does no start until run_server ends
    await server()
    # await f()
```

... the call to server causes client to be blocked.
In particular it get stuck in the call to

```
   await loop.sock_accept(sock)
```

and the client() will not start until server() exits.
Why?

Replacing `await server()` with a difference async functions:

```
    #await server()
    await f()
```

allows client to run()

The behavior is the same for Python 3.7 .. 3.10

Similarly, we can flip which is added as as a task and which is immediately await. The task fails to run in both:

```
    if 1:
        loop.create_task(server())  # Does no start until server ends
        await client()
    else:
        loop.create_task(client())  # Does no start until client ends
        await server()
```

Full example:

```
import asyncio
import socket

host, port = ('localhost', 15555)
# host, port = ('127.0.0.1', 15555)
ACCEPT_TIMEOUT = 2

async def server():
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print("Creating server")
    sock.bind((host, port))
    sock.listen(8)
    sock.setblocking(False)  # sock_accept asks for non-blockin
    sock.settimeout(ACCEPT_TIMEOUT)

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    while True:
        print("ACCEPTING CONNECTIONS")
        try:
            client, _ = await loop.sock_accept(sock)
        except socket.timeout:
            print("ACCEPT TIMEOUT")
            return

        print("123 5")
        loop.create_task(handle_client(client))
        print("123 6")

async def client():
    print("Sending .. ")
    while True:
        try:
            tcp_reader, tcp_writer = await asyncio.open_connection(host, port)
            break
        except ConnectionRefusedError:
            print("Refused")
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

    print("Sending .. OK")
    msg = b"Message"
    while True:
        tcp_writer.write(msg)
        tcp_writer.drain()
        r = tcp_reader.read()
        assert r == msg

async def handle_client(client):  # Never reached
    print("Handle client...")
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    request = None
    while request != 'quit':
        request = (await loop.sock_recv(client, 255))
        await loop.sock_sendall(client, request)
    client.close()

async def f():
    print("f..")
    asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("f..done")

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    if 1:
        loop.create_task(client())  # Does no start until client ends
        await server()
        # await f()
    else:
        loop.create_task(server())  # Does no start until server ends
        await client()
    
if __name__=='__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: I'd like to set a timeout for sock_accept. -- if nobody connects, I want to close the socket (free it for reuse) and notify another component.

Comment: Using asyncio.create_task makes no difference.

Comment: I tried adding `loop.` everywhere above in order to be sure each component was really using the same loop.
(In a different version loop is set once globally, and reference instead of asyncio.get_event_loop() ...  result was the same)

Comment: You CAN be sure you use the same loop everywhere because all of them are in an async block and you only ever create one asyncio runtime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that on Linux `sock.settimeout()` overrules `sock.setblocking(false)`.

A couple of changes that made your code work for me:

- Remove `sock.settimeout(...)` and use asyncio's timeout functionality instead
- Use context managers for closing the socket properly, to avoid leaving an unclosed socket behind
- Add the `REUSEADDR` flag to keep the socket from being stuck in `TIME_WAIT` state when running the example repeatedly

```py
async def server():
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
        print("Creating server")
        sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        sock.bind((host, port))
        sock.listen(8)
        sock.setblocking(False)  # sock_accept asks for non-blockin

        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

        while True:
            print("ACCEPTING CONNECTIONS")
            try:
                client, _ = await asyncio.wait_for(loop.sock_accept(sock), timeout=ACCEPT_TIMEOUT)
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                print("ACCEPT TIMEOUT")
                return

            print("123 5")
            loop.create_task(handle_client(client))
            print("123 6")
```